# sessionStorage into array and print all values in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, session-storage

I am currently trying to store an array into `sessionStorage` and then retrieve the data from `sessionStorage`. Then, store the `sessionStorage` data back into an array.

```
var testArray = ["Shirt", "Bottom", "Shoes"];
window.sessionStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(testArray));
var storedArray = JSON.parse('[' + sessionStorage.getItem("items") + ']');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < storedArray.length; i++) {
     alert(storedArray[i]);
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("items"));`.. What made you concatenate `[ \ ]` there.. ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is already stored as an array, you don't need the brackets. What you are doing is putting the original array in a new array.

try this:

```
var testArray = ["Shirt", "Bottom", "Shoes"];
window.sessionStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(testArray));
var storedArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("items"));//no brackets
var i;
for (i = 0; i < storedArray.length; i++) {
             alert(storedArray[i]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/517x5rcg/

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much. I had no idea about the JSON.parse function! :D

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap the array with `[]`. `sessionStorage.getItem("items")` returns the JSON stringified array, you are wrapping the array with another array. Your problem is the `alert` function that converts the array into a string (just like joined array elements by calling the `Array.prototype.join` method), this is because `alert` can only show strings. This probably makes you think that there is no array. Use `console.log` for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let testArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
    sessionStorage.setItem("items",testArray);
    let storedArray = sessionStorage.getItem("items").split(",");
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < storedArray.length; i++) {
                 alert(storedArray[i]);
    }
```